# In Android Studio, why am I setting after the spell has no effect

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio always automatically checks the spelling of a word problem and shows wavy lines. I follow the tutorial tips online canceled spelling typo, determined after you restart the IDE has no effect

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The wavy line doesn't indicate typo. It's mean this method never used.
Also, uncheck on Android lint too.

Comment: Manh is correct, AS (and its core, Intellij) tries to tell you what you have and have not used. If you hover over the error, it will say that it is unused and ask if you want to remove it or not.